# DateTime.Parse is dropping milliseconds from DataRow?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing

I have a `DATETIME` field in SQL Server called `EntryTime` with a value of `2020-11-04 18:55:19.437`. As you can see, the milliseconds element is present with a value of `437`. However, if I parse this value from my `DataRow`:

```
DateTime entryTime = DateTime.MinValue;
if (row["EntryTime"] != DBNull.Value)
    entryTime = DateTime.Parse(row["EntryTime"]?.ToString());
```

I then get everything **except** the millisecond value.

My assumption here is that `.ToString()` is dropping the milliseconds, and I've confirmed that in my immediate window:

[image: Immediate 1]

---

Why are the milliseconds being dropped?

Comment: What is `row` that it wont convert directly to a `DateTime`?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp updated my question to point out that it was a `DataRow`, and I learned during my research that it was already converted directly, which is why `.ToString()` was dropping the milliseconds.

Comment: The proposed duplicate solves another problem altogether and only implies the answer to this question through educated reasoning which makes it unclear to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The milliseconds are being dropped because of how `.ToString()` *specifically*, works on `DateTime` objects. Per the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ToString) on `DateTime.ToString()` (emphasis mine):

> ToString()
> -
> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
> string representation **using the formatting conventions of the
> current culture**.

Here, `row["EntryTime"]` is an `object`, but more importantly, it's a boxed `DateTime`:

[image: Immediate 1]

Therefore converting it to string and then parsing it is unnecessary. In reality, you should make sure the value of `row["EntryTime"]` is not `DBNull.Value`, and then unbox the value by explicitly casting to `DateTime`:

```
DateTime entryTime = DateTime.MinValue;
if (row["EntryTime"] != DBNull.Value)
    entryTime = (DateTime)row["EntryTime"];
```

This will give you the `DateTime` object with the `Millisecond` property still in-tact:

[image: Immediate 2]